# Read csv files from a folder based on condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, directory, fnmatch

I want to read csv files from a folder based on condition. I just want to read csv files that include “1441” in the filename. I used fnmatch, but it doesn’t work. Can anyone help?

```
path_to_parent = r"C:\Users\Desktop\books/chapter_1"

for csv_file in os.listdir(path_to_parent):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(csv_file,'1441'):
        my_file = pd.read_csv(path_to_parent+csv_file)
    else:
        print('error')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need wildcards around `1441` to match the rest of the filename. Otherwise it's looking for the exact filename `1441`.

Also, you're not adding the directory separator between `path_to_parent` and `csv_file` when you concatenate them. It's best to use `os.path.join()` for portability.

```
for csv_file in os.listdir(path_to_parent):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(csv_file,'*1441*'):
        my_file = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_to_parent, csv_file))
    else:
        print('error')
```

I also recommend using `glob.glob()` instead. It will do the wildcard matching for you, and it will return full paths so you don't have to concatenate each time through the loop.

```
for csv_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_to_parent, '*1441*')):
    my_file = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try different approach with slight modification to your if statement.

```py
for csv_file in os.listdir(path_to_parent):
        if '1441' in csv_file:
            my_file = pd.read_csv(f'{path_to_parent}/{csv_file}')
        else:
            print('error')
```